# XFCE menus override shortcut keys

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I have recently installed debian 8 with xfce 4.10, and I am annoyed by the following:

Menus (like e.g. the one that pops up if I press ctrl-esc) overrides the access to short cuts.

Normally I have that the short cut ctrl-alt-t opens a terminal, but if I press ctrl-esc and then this sequence when the menu is still open then nothing happens.

Other menus that block the short cuts are the roll-down menus from the panels, and even sometimes when parts of the panel is in focus.

**Question**: Is there a way to force short cut keys to *always* work?

Comment: You're right about that. It blocks keyboard shortcuts when the Applications Menu is open on both the desktop context menu and if it is a panel item. I have noticed however that the Whisker Menu does not block keyboard shortcuts. https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin

Comment: I tried to install the whiskermenu package, but nothing happened - do I need to configure something somewhere?

Comment: It should be in the Debian repository. You can install by the following in terminal: sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin

Comment: Then you would just add it to a panel. Panel Preferences > Items  To apply a keyboard shortcut for the menu to pop up, the command is: xfce4-popup-whiskermenu

Comment: It is better to install packages from repositories when available than installing a deb package. This way you get updates to the programs when you update your system.

Comment: Oh - you misunderstand - I installed the package, but nothing have changed.